# Prove hypothesis that $\sigma_1 \leq \sigma_2$in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, variance, f-test

My condition

$
X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\,\sigma^{2}_1)\,.
     $ where mean = 6, sd = 2.5, n=16

$
Q \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\,\sigma^{2}_2)\,.
     $ where mean = 8, sd = 4, n=18

I need to prove $H:\sigma^{2}_1 <= \sigma^{2}_2 $ where $H_0$ is $:\sigma^{2}_1 >= \sigma^{2}_2$ with significance level: 0.05

My solution in R:

```
x_distr <- rnorm(n=16, mean=6, sd=2.5)
q_distr <- rnorm(n=18, mean=8.5, sd=4)
```

Now I don't know which test to choose, but I decided to use F-Test:

```
var.test(x_distr, q_distr, 
     alternative = c("less"),
     conf.level = 0.95);
```

But I don't know how to confirm $H$ using test output. Could you help me?

Output :

```
F test to compare two variances

data:  x_distr and q_distr
F = 0.42046, num df = 15, denom df = 17, p-value = 0.0492
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is less than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.9957639
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.4204604
```

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post to show us the output? It is a bit difficult to offer an interpretation of something we cannot see.

Comment: @mdewey sorry. I have made edit

Answer (score 1):

So the $p$-value is 0.0492 which if you had decided in advance to use the 0.05 level of significance would mean that you could reject the null hypothesis that the two variances were equal in favour of your alternative hypothesis that x has a smaller variance than q. The confidence interval from 0 to 0.996 suggests that (a) you do not have much information here as it is very wide (b) that in the long run 95% of the time the true ratio of the variances would lie between 0 and 0.996.